# Создать функцию makeAbbr(words) которая берет строку и возвращает аббревиатуру

Tags: javascript

у меня такая задачка щас:

Создать функцию makeAbbr(words) которая берет строку и возвращает из нее первую букву каждого слова и формирует слова (аббревиатуру) из этих первых букв

Мой код выглядит вот так на данный момент:

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  const startWord = 'Witcher is the most Clever and Smart and Dangerous one';
  let resultWord = '';

  for (const char of words) {
    if (words.charAt(char)) {
      resultWord += char;
    }
  };

  return resultWord;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Как именно помочь-то?

Comment: Не могу понять что я делаю не так что оно не хочет работать

Comment: Тут должно получиться WITMCASADO ?

Comment: А откуда return вне функции? А откуда words взялось? А что за переменная makeAbbr в коде? И почему это не функция у вас?

Comment: А как зайти в это WITMCASADO? И return не вне функции, просто первая строчка с обьявлением функции не захватилась

Comment: Теперь поправлено

Comment: окей... теперь хотелось бы понять две вещи: что такое startWord   . оно на что-то влияет? и кто такой middleWord

Comment: startWord - это начальная переменная для входящей строки, а middleWord - это была переменная для промежуточного результата, но в итоге она тут уже не к месту по ходу

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае нужно

1. Разбить строку со словами с помощью метода **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**. Получим массив со словами
2. Пробегаемся по массиву слов и применяем метод, берем нулевой элемент каждой строчки (так можно обращаться к строке) и складываем в переменную
3. Применяем к переменной метод [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) и конкатенируем этот результат с `resultWord`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  return words
    .split(' ')
    .reduce((prevVal, curWord) => prevVal + (curWord ? curWord[0]: ''), '')
    .toUpperCase()
}
console.log(makeAbbr('Witcher is the most   Clever and Smart and Dangerous one'))
```

Comment: Хотел было минусануть, но вовремя вспомнил, что из-за низкой пока репутации Вы не видите удалённых ответов ("репа" нужна > 10K). Поверьте, что там были представлены более лаконичные варианты. А удалены они были авторами в пользу ответа, который даёт автору вопроса хоть немного самостоятельно подумать над решением.

Comment: split(/\s+/) можно сделать, чтоб лишних проверок не делать

Comment: автору вопроса нужно давать варианты для осознания методов решения. Поэтому не понимаю, зачем удалять правильные ответы

Comment: @SanyaH: ох, о каком осознании речь, если есть "copy'n'paste"?